# Wordpress multiple database

Tags: wordpress

i am creating a website in word press CMS.i want to sink the blog into the website with new database,i want separate word press theme and separate word press database for my blog and the URL  must be concatenated with /
e.g my original website link is wwww.example.com
now i want to create wwww.example.com/blog 
with new theme and new database 
i had tried to create multi site in word press but it did not allow me to create multi site with name BLOG because it is the reserved word in word press.also multi site is using the same database
any solution

Comment: i repeat the question. i want to create blog with seperate database and new theme in single wordpress installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new brand new wordpress installation under your chosen subdirectory.

Comment: what about the url? how the url will be same? e.g
my first installation has www.example.com
and how could second installtaion have www.example.com/newinstallation link ?

Comment: That is how WP works. You can have one installation in example.com and one in example.com/new